# DRF, consistent api for foreignkey relations

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Suppose you want to show nested data when reading.
Also suppose that you want to only allow changing the id of the foreign key.

Hence the following definition arises, but the problem is they use the same variable `order_case` and I get when updating via `{"order_case": 477}`.

> ValueError: Cannot assign "477": "OrderCaseRevision.order_case" must
>   be a "OrderCase" instance.

```
class OrderCaseRevisionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    order_case = OrderCaseSerializer(read_only=True)
    order_case = serializers.IntegerField(write_only=True)
```

I could do the following to mitigate the problem, but I don't like the fact that you usually use foreign key name like `order_case` to update the foreign key field and here you are making an exception that you have to use `order_case_id`.

```
class OrderCaseRevisionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    order_case = OrderCaseSerializer(read_only=True)
    order_case_id = serializers.IntegerField(write_only=True)
```

Comment: Please show your models too.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I solved this problem..

Define custom general field:

```
class MySelectField(serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.serializer_class = kwargs.pop('serializer_class', None)
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

    def to_representation(self, value):
        obj = self.queryset.filter(pk=value.pk).first()
        return self.serializer_class(obj).data
```

Use it in your serializer:

```
order_case = MySelectField(
    queryset=OrderCase.objects.all(),
    serializer_class=OrderCaseSerializer
)
```

You could probably simplify it further by pulling queryset attr from serializer, therefore having only serializer argument for the custom field.